# while-list gives strange values

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

i get the next post vars from a form:

```
$_POST['segment'][2]
$_POST['segment'][3]
$_POST['segment'][4]
$_POST['segment'][5]
```

These are checkboxes from a form.

Don't ask me why, but the posted data is transformed to:
$IN["segment"]

I check them with:

```
if($IN['segment'][5])
  $podo_segment = 5;
elseif($IN['segment'][4])
   $podo_segment = 4;
elseif($IN['segment'][3])
   $podo_segment = 3;
elseif($IN['segment'][2])
   $podo_segment = 2;
else
   $podo_segment = 'NULL';
```

podo means feet:)

Then i insert the (highest) value into the mysql. 
(a higher value means that lower values are included too, that is why just 1 field is used)

I have to update older values but a mask is used and i really dont understand how this is done so no idea how to transform/update this to new values 2,3,4 or 5.

```
$segmask = 0;
while (list($a,$b)=@each($IN["segment"]))
   $segmask += pow(2,$a);
```

I tried php.net but could not make any sense of it. at least nothing more then $segmask becomes a value of 2^$a. (what's $a,$b and $b doesn't seem to do anything???)
but the resulting values in mysql for example:

5 gives 32, (looks ok to me: 2^5)

No other choices then 2,3,4 and/or 5, gives values like:

```
9977932
16273612
18366668
24662092
16448
17846476
18370636
34619404
270024716
18370780
9982092
34623564
9977980
512
16386
1064964
2
37240844
35143692
1064972
9977868
16388
2148548620
269500428
2148548668
268976140
1107836940
11026444
2149072908
1589260
```

At the end i need to update a new mysql-field with values 2,3,4 or 5 based upon this older field.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't like the `while (list() = each())` structure. It looks messy and confusing and 99.9% of the time `foreach` will do the same job just as efficiently, if not more so.

Change

```
while (list($a,$b)=@each($IN["segment"]))
  $segmask += pow(2,$a);
```

to

```
foreach ($IN["segment"] as $key => $val)
  $segmask += pow(2, $key);
```

...and see if you still have the same problem. If you do, then the problem lies somewhere else, and I will probably have some more questions about exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I myself never have used while (list() = each()) structure. I am just debugging someone elses website. The problem is this code is used to insert this data but the search engine does not always give the right results. To prevent a complete rewrite of that website, i added the new field, so for new members it works, but i have to update it for existing members. I am trying to find a correlation between 2,3,4,5 and the old (masked) numbers. But for 400 members i have 101 different old values:(

Comment: I don't quite understand what the mask is supposed to do/represent... Is it supposed to track a combination of options? So options 2 & 4 would be 20, options 2 & 3 would be 12, 2 only would be 4, etc etc? Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: looking at the numbers, they all seem to be produced from powers of 2 (for example, `pow(2,14) + pow(2,1) = 16386` and `pow(2,20) + pow(2,14) + pow(2,2) = 1064964`) but how to interpret/reverse this to something meaningful I have no idea...